# Android - tracking browser activity

Tags: android, browser, performance-testing

I'm looking to develop an application to track how long a site takes to load on the default android browser. Does the browser have any method of tracking when the site is fully loaded?

Comment: I pretty much doubt it. You can start loading a site by calling an intent. However, you have no idea which browser will handle the intent. Your best solution probably would be to use `WebView`, which uses the same rendering toolkit as the Android browser.

Comment: Will webview provide the same headers and User agent in the request, or is that configurable within webview? The request and behaviour of the browser needs to be as similar as possible to the native browser.

Comment: No idea...should be easy enough to test that though.

Answer (score 0):

on page started and on page finished are the methods to 
get the  the start time and end time of loading of the webview

```
                WebView search_webview;
               search_webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.show_webview);
              search_webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
        }
        @Override
           public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap                                 favicon) {

             super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
           }
           @Override
           public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
           _dialog.dismiss();
           super.onPageFinished(view, url);
           }

           @Override
           public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

            try{

             _dialog.dismiss();
             Toast.makeText(ShowWebView.this, "NO Internet Connection Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }catch (Exception e) {
             // TODO: handle exception
            }
           }
    });
```

Comment: I was wanting to use the native browser but the webview sufficed, thanks.